# Create Google Earth zoom in

Tags: jquery, flash, slideshow, google-earth-plugin

Is there any way to create a zoom in to a location like Google Earth for a site?

I think, I can do this with a slide show in Flash or jQuery, but I would like to know if there is a better alternative way!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Google Earth API Demo Gallery](http://code.google.com/apis/earth/documentation/demogallery.html)  you will find samples of what you need !

Comment: Thank you!! I didn't know that there is something like that... With the camera control I made what I wanted!!!

Answer (score 0):

I once did something similar with Flash. I would use that, especially if you intend to have any interactivity on whatever image you're zooming into.

Comment: Google Maps doesn't use Flash, and is quite interactive. Why would something that emulates it need to?

Comment: He's not talking about "Google Maps", but rather "Google Earth", which plays a movie of zooming in to a location from space.